# HTML Input Multiple Type Attribute

Tags: html, css, input

If this has been asked before then please check if it is the same.

I'm using Materialize css and I want to know how to use multiple type i.e.

```
<input id="login_password" type="search|password" placeholder="Password">
```

when using type="search" it gives me an awesome input design now i want to use that in other input types.

I've tried two type i.e

```
<input id="login_password" type="search" type="password" placeholder="Password">
```

now its like type="password" never existed

Comment: You can't give 2 types to an input. You can't say a search box is also a password box.

Comment: ok so its not possible then. I need to modify the css for search attribute... annoying lol.. thank you btw

Comment: Maybe you can just get the CSS rules and apply them to the other type you want.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  Select images: <input  type="file" type="submit"  name="input" >
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

see here im giving  assigning types for a single input..if you do that it will consider only the first one type.it wont consider the second one.. so what i am trying to say is you can't assign multiple type for a single input tag.